# Saving each layer as serparate file but with master template

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, png, save

I recently figured out how to save each layer as a separate file in photoshop.

I do this when editing a gif image.

Now, however, i have a layer below (layer 0) and a layer on top(72) and i want those two layers to be included in all the other layers from 1-71 when they are each saved as a separate file.

For example if i take layer4.jpg i should be able to see both layer 0 and layer 72 in it.

Comment: Hi, Have you tried layer comps? Its is useful in this case but it might not be very productive if you will only do it once!

Comment: I do not know what layer comps are.

Comment: Links to Layer Comps,

http://helpx.adobe.com/en/photoshop/using/layer-comps.html

http://tv.adobe.com/watch/understanding-adobe-photoshop-cs6/layer-comps-/

Let me know if you need help, I can clarify what you need to do.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to this?